# Monit "method not defined"

Tags: monit

I'm currently trying to use monit to purge my `/var/log` partition from specific files whenever the partition runs out of free disk space.
I created a file named `toto` and tried this test after reading the doc:

```
check filesystem log path /var/log
    if space usage > 1% for 3 cycles then exec "/usr/bin/find /var/log/ -iname 'toto' -type f -exec rm -f {} \;"
```

When I start monit, it prints `'log' start skipped -- method not defined` and I haven't found yet what it means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at my own monit logs, I see this happen if for some reason Monit is trying to start a service for which no `start` method has been declared. Here's an example from the [documentation](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#SERVICE-METHODS):

```
check process mmonit with pidfile /usr/local/mmonit/mmonit/logs/mmonit.pid
   start program = "/usr/local/mmonit/bin/mmonit" as uid "mmonit" and gid "mmonit"
   stop program = "/usr/local/mmonit/bin/mmonit stop" as uid "mmonit" and gid "mmonit"
```

This service has the `start` and `stop` method defined. You do not specify such methods for your `log` service, so they are undefined and Monit cannot do anything if somehow it is requested to `start`, `stop`, or `restart` (which is a third method) the `log` service.

You don't need to define them if Monit is not actually going to be tasked with starting or stoping the service. I have a disk space test where the methods are not defined, and it works just fine.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's a lot clearer now.
Monit still won't execute my find and remove command though, is there a way to manually start a specific check?

Until now I've been using only `monit start all -v` but it really does nothing but print things it doesn't really do...

Comment: I don't know of a specific command to cause monit to check a service right away. Perhaps doing `monit unmonitor log` followed by `monit monitor log` will trigger a check right away. I see you make it wait for 3 cycles though. So it won't be instantaneous even if it does trigger the check.

Comment: That's right, thanks again.
I removed the '3 cycles' part and run `monit unmonitor log` followed by `monit monitor log` but no more luck though.
Monit also says `State file '.monit.state': Unable to truncate` when I run `monit unmonitor log` by the way?